# Prevent window.onblur from impacting the dom

Tags: javascript

I have a chrome extension that submits a by sending a keydown event. It works the first time, but not the second, IF you click outside of the window running the extension.

In order to stop that default behavior and keep the form submitting with the event code I've tried to stop the `onblur` event from firing.

```
window.onblur = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

However, this hasn't fixed the problem. Is there a way to keep focus on a window even when the user clicks outside of it?

Comment: `Is there a way to keep focus on a window even when the user clicks outside of it?` I certainly hope not. Can you even begin to imagine the nightmare that would be? Think of the security problems if a browser window could hijack the system and force itself to constantly keep focus no matter where the user clicks.

Comment: @gforce301 Man I miss the early 2000's when you could do stuff like that.....Nothing like spawning a window without a close button. lol

Comment: "It works the first time, but not the second," It is unclear what that actually means.

Comment: @epascarello the first form submission works even if you blur the page, but the subsequent ones do not

Comment: okay so does the page get focus back by clicking on it?

Comment: @epascarello yes. so whatever is happening after the keydown event when you're blurred prevents the `sendkeys` function from firing. I'm putting together a MVE (minimum viable extension right now)

Comment: @epascarello tried to maken MVE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528086/chrome-extension-sendkeys-not-firing-properly-after-keydown-event-window-blu